# Flex layout: div on desktop takes place below, but on mobile last of all content

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive

Making my first flex layout (see attached photo to see desired placement for sections in desktop and small devices).

Div (title "License") depending on screen width needs to change its order: on mobile devices shown as last, but on desktop to take place right after text in first column on left.

Is this even possible with only flex? Perhaps grid layout model should be considered instead?

My flex example is straight forward except on desktop to get the "license" div below (because of flex-direction:row;) I use sort of a hack:

```
.break-column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

So far on mobile devices design works as it should, where as on desktop the div is still shown as last.

My structure for HTML might be wrong. Pointing to right direction would help a bunch!

Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/virsis12/j6sc8g5t/13/

[image: dekstop to mobile]

Comment: Problematic part is the "licence" section using flex, you may need to duplicate that section for phone(show/hide) or use js. Might be wise to advise your designers to avoid such designs, and make responsiveness friendly designs

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. We will respect CSS and leave Licence under description, meaning its placement will not change depending on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this layout using flexbox

1. Use javascipt to add `resize` event listener on window and when screen width becomes smaller than a particular width, place the `.content-license` element at the end of the web page
2. You can duplicate the `.content-license` element, one placed in `.content__wrapper` and other placed at the end of the web page. On large screen, hide the one at the end of the web page and on smaller screens, hide the one in `.content__wrapper`

Following code has used the latter approach as there's no javascript involved in this approach.

```css
.home__flex {
  display: flex;
  background: rgb(230, 253, 214);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cover__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px;
}

.content-license {
  padding: 15px;
}

.cover__wrapper .content-license {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.cover__wrapper img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  align-self: center;
}

.links__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .content-license {
    display: none;
  }
  .cover__wrapper .content-license {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .cover__wrapper {
    flex-basis: 20%;
    padding: 35px;
  }
  .cover__wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 850px) {
  .cover__wrapper {
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
  .links__wrapper {
    padding: 0 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container__home">
  <div class="home__flex">
    <div class="cover__wrapper">
      <img class="cover" src="https://i.ibb.co/Kx6Hm9w/dang.png" alt="dang" border="0">
      <div class="content-descr">
        <p>
          Until recently, the prevailing view assumed lorem ipsum was born as a nonsense text. “It's not Latin, though it looks like it, and it actually says nothing, After magazine answered a curious reader.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-license">
        <h2>Licence</h2>
        <p>
          Licensed under a Creative Commons attribution-noncommercial license.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="links__wrapper">
      <div class="table-of-contents">
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <ol>
          <li>Until recently, the prevailing view </li>
          <li>It's not Latin, though it looks</li>
          <li>Its ‘words’ loosely approximate the frequency</li>
          <li>which is why at a glance it looks pretty real</li>
          <li>Until recently, the prevailing view </li>
          <li>It's not Latin, though it looks</li>
          <li>Its ‘words’ loosely approximate the frequency</li>
          <li>which is why at a glance it looks pretty real</li>
          <li>Until recently, the prevailing view </li>
          <li>It's not Latin, though it looks</li>
          <li>Its ‘words’ loosely approximate the frequency</li>
          <li>which is why at a glance it looks pretty real</li>
          <li>Until recently, the prevailing view </li>
          <li>It's not Latin, though it looks</li>
          <li>Its ‘words’ loosely approximate the frequency</li>
          <li>which is why at a glance it looks pretty real</li>
          <li>Until recently, the prevailing view </li>
          <li>It's not Latin, though it looks</li>
          <li>Its ‘words’ loosely approximate the frequency</li>
          <li>which is why at a glance it looks pretty real</li>
          <li>Until recently, the prevailing view </li>
          <li>It's not Latin, though it looks</li>
          <li>Its ‘words’ loosely approximate the frequency</li>
          <li>which is why at a glance it looks pretty real</li>
          <li>Until recently, the prevailing view </li>
          <li>It's not Latin, though it looks</li>
          <li>Its ‘words’ loosely approximate the frequency</li>
          <li>which is why at a glance it looks pretty real</li>
          <li>Until recently, the prevailing view </li>
          <li>It's not Latin, though it looks</li>
          <li>Its ‘words’ loosely approximate the frequency</li>
          <li>which is why at a glance it looks pretty real</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="other-links">
        <h2>Other</h2>
        <ul class="links">
          <li><a href="code">After magazine</a></li>
          <li><a href="errata.html">looks pretty cool</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Lots of laugh</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break-column"></div>
    <div class="content-license">
      <h2>Licence</h2>
      <p>
        Licensed under a Creative Commons attribution-noncommercial license.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or duplicate the licence section and show/hide based on width

Comment: @Huangism yes, i think, duplicating license section is more efficient then adding `resize` event listener on window. Making some changes. Will update soon

Comment: Yea it's a small section and depending on the technology used, it could be defined in one place so maintenance is easy

Comment: Unusual problems are solved by Javascript. Both of you, thanks for the help! I learned something new today.

Comment: updated my answer. I suggest you use the second approach (suggested by @Huangism) as i have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.. Your question is very confusing. However, if you're wanting to change flex-order use the order property to rearrange your divs how you'd like. This along with @media queries should solve your problem.

For example,

```
.home__flex {
    display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .cover__wrapper { order: 2; }
    .content-license { order: 1; }
    .links__wrapper { order: 3; }
    .other-links { order: 4; }
}
```

This would move your *.content-license* div to the first spot on screens larger than 900px followed by: *.cover__wrapper*, then *.links__wrapper*, then *.other-links* ***Make sure each div is assigned an order**.

Please refer to [W3Schools Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) for more information.
Try it, [W3Schools Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_order_2)

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear, hope it helps. Look at the attached photo where the License section is on desktop and on mobile. License div on desktop is visually aligned next to content. In my case just the order will not be enough. Already tried.

Comment: This cannot be done with order to move license the way it is in the photo